# Как обрабатывать обращения к боту VK асинхронно, чтобы пользователю не приходилось ждать, пока предыдущий получит ответ?

Tags: python, асинхронность

Сейчас мой бот в Вк обрабатывает сообщения синхронно:

```
1) Получил сообщение от пользователя, 
2) Формирует для него ответ и отправляет
*При этом если напишет кто-то ещё, то бот не ответит ему, пока не закончит с предыдущим пользователем.
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы бот получал сообщение от пользователя и сразу переходил к следующему, даже если на предыдущее сообщение, которое получил бот ответ еще на этапе формирования.

Ранее я уже задавал похожий вопрос и мне посоветовали библиотеку "multiprocessing", однако я не понимаю, каким образом её можно применить конкретно в моем случае. Вот пример того, как работает сейчас (синхронно) с использованием longpoll:

```
import vk_api

def main():
    # Подключение по токену сообщества, создание объекта longpoll
    session = vk_api.VkApi(token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(session, group_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        # Если получено сообщение
        if (event.object.text):
            # Формируем ответ
            generate_response(event.object.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы эта часть кода, принимающая сообщения и формирующая ответ работала асинхронно и пользователю не приходилось ждать, пока предыдущий пользователь получит ответ?

Comment: Выносите обработку каждого `event` в отдельный процесс, а не запускайте в процессе Вашу последовательную программу...

Comment: Сами ответы можно отправлять асинхронно, то есть непоследовательно?

Comment: @sanmai, если человек написал и "ждет ответа" и в этот момент написал что-то ещё, то сначала должно обработаться предыдущее сообщение (из соображений безопасности).

Comment: Я имею ввиду поддерживает ли сам класс VkApi асинхронную работу? Например, если вы из соседних тредов начнёте _одновременно_ отправлять ответы разным людям, они пройдут корректно, или перемешаются? В принципе это можно [напрямую у разработчика спросить](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/issues).

Comment: Используйте _асинхронный сервер_ (или `Celery`) и `Callback API`, вместо попытки адаптировать под это `longPoll`.

Comment: @nomnoms12, а почему в случае Callback'a это работает асинхронно? Мне бы очень хотелось понять этот момент. Правильно ли я понимаю, что используя callback, всю "асинхронность" ему придаёт вебсервер на котором я его принимаю, по аналогии с сайтом, который могут запрашивать сразу сотни посетителей? Как это работает на низком уровне?

Comment: @CoffeeinTime Да, Вы всё правильно понимаете. ВК будет присылать Вам запросы, а обрабатываться они будут асинхронно. Стоит отметить, что не обязательно изучать для этого асинхронный фреймворк, видел (и сам использую) реализацию через `Celery` (`Nginx` + `Gunicorn` + `Django` + `Celery`).

Comment: @nomnoms12, вы принимаете callback, после чего создается задача в celery?

Comment: @CoffeeinTime Да, всё так. Способ довольно гибкий, так как можно создавать разные очереди с разным приоритетом и запускать задачи из других задач.

Comment: @CoffeeinTime Чем вам не нравится идея использовать AIOVK? Там можно и Celery подключить и в потоках/процессах в случае чего запустить, ибо asynаcio позволяет это делать. Если ваша задача CPU-Bound запускаете обработку event в процессе, иначе даете ее asyncio(там приоритет можно контролировать)

Comment: @Flyme, я не уверен в библиотеке aiovk, но мб я ошибаюсь. Правильно ли я понимаю, что помимо асинхронного приема запросов (с чем может справиться и любой другой вебсервер, исходя из вышесказанного), она также может асинхронно выполнять исходящее запросы к VK API? Например одновременно получать фотографии и в этот же момент загружать видеозаписи. Если это так, то я думаю, что это преимущество не критически важно, так как в VK API для этого есть метод множественного запроса. И я бы все же мог обойтись обычным aiohttp для приема и celery для асинхронного формирования ответа, добавляя задачи.

Comment: @CoffeeinTime мне кажется вы плохо знамы с асинхронным программированием. Aiovk построен на aiohttp, который построен на asyncio. Все действия в том числе передача и приём данных асинхронные. Асинхронность это не как вы пишите «одновременно», а это конкурентность. Для I/O-bound задач лучше асинхронности вам не найти. Для CPU-bound задач можно запустить процесс или поток, ответ которого отдать на исполнение асинхронности. 1 асинхронный процесс питона выдерживает около 2000 RPS при правильной реализации. Думаю вам этого хватит :)

Comment: @Flyme, отлично, вы взорвали мне мозг)

Comment: @CoffeeinTime попробую проще. Все задачи, которые блокируют исполнение друго кода, но выполняются быстро лучше запускать в конкурентной среде (задачи выполняются по очереди, но могут быть поделены на приостанавливаемые подзадачи), т.е. асинхронно, это все I/O bound. Все что тяжелое, например математические операции занимающие секунды, отправляйте в отдельный процесс, asyncio позволяет вернуть их ответ. RPS это соединений в секунду, т.е. 2000 у вас ваша асинхронность выдержит. Короче для 99% ботов в ВК асинхронность лучшее решение Но, ее надо уметь писать, а если не умеете, учиться

Answer (score 2):

Как уже вам ответили, выносите это в отдельный процесс. 
Могу предложить использовать асинхронную библиотеку, например [aiovk](https://github.com/Fahreeve/aiovk). Это с случае когда мы говорим об асинхронности.

Но судя по вопросу, вам нужно просто не блокировать работу с другими сообщениями(что-бы бот продолжал работать пока обрабатывает тяжелый запрос). Для этого будет достаточно создать поток.

```
from threading import Thread


def send_response(message):
    print(" <-", message)


for i in range(100):
    # Таким образом можно вызывать функции, которые нужно обрабатывать длительное время
    Thread(target=send_response, args=(i,)).start()
```

Хочу уточнить, что создание потока хоть и выглядит на первым взгляд быстрым, но на самом деле требует большие затраты по времени. И если формирование запроса не занимает реально много времени, то в большинстве случаев создавать потоки не стоит.

Советую изучить темы многопоточности(threading), многопроцессинга(multiprocessing), асинхронности(asyncio). Следует понимать когда и что применять.

Comment: Касаемо уточнения: можно использовать пул потоков, но если боту действительно приходит парочка сообщений в секунду, то многопоточность тут вряд ли поможет.