# Как сделать чтобы бот обрабатывал сообщения во время использования time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот

[Похожая тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064197/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-vk-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE)

Делаю бота для Вконтакте, но столкнулся с проблемой когда мне нужно отправлять сообщения с длинной задержкой, но при этом чтобы другие сообщения обрабатывались.

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
  if message == 'работать':
      send('Вы начали работать')
      time.sleep(60)
      send('Вы закончили работать')
  if message...
#другие команды
```

как можно сделать это? прошу с примером...

Comment: Используйте потоки.

Comment: Даже в похожей теме там все написано про них же.

Comment: Чем вам не помогла похожая тема?

Comment: уточнить что использовать, threading, multiprocessing или asyncio

Comment: подмечу, мне нужна не асинхронная отправка сообщений, а обработка других во время действия time.sleep()